# For an architecture *lacking a stack or memory allocation*, what is the most expressive programming language?

Tags: compiler-construction, embedded, abstract-syntax-tree

I work on a proprietary sequencer having a few bytes of free RAM; several hundred bytes statically allocated; 8 registers including PC; no indirection (in C, a "pointer"); no stack.

There is no `MOV` instruction: to move `M` into `K`, you must write `CLX A; ORX M; STX K` which much complicates dependency resolution, or at least optimization. Many operations work only on specific registers: for example, a 32-bit right shift uses `K` in the upper word and `M` in the lower word.

So to me, the obvious choice of C for embedded applications are out because no pointers or function calls are possible. Most higher-level programming languages have arithmetic expressions, so this doesn't help to narrow down our choices.

Most important of all is absolute minimum code size, so optimization is key.

My inclination is to compile Lisp expressions as a form of macro assembler, because the programmer can optimize his own higher-level operations, for example, to write a `XOR` instruction.

I'm sure this isn't the first project to ever have these sorts of restrictions; how has this been solved in the past?

Comment: Fortran sounds like something that could be tuned for that chip. The more details you give, the better the answers are.

Comment: "no indirection (in C, a "pointer"); no stack." - If there is a reason I would ever quit a job voluntarily, that would surely be having to work with such a device.

Comment: What kind of applications is this device used to implement?  How much code can it contain?  It really has *no* indirection of any kind? You could tell us the name of the controller if it is a commercial device.

Comment: Highly proprietary, micropower heuristics. @FUZxxl sorry, I'd love to, but I've probably said too much already :)

Comment: OK there does exist indirection. Memory is organized into 16 some odd pages of 16 rows. You can change pages, so in theory, you could allocate a page to be a stack frame of size 16. However I have a managerial constraint that we *not add any significant amount of memory* for cost reasons. So, each page is a homogenous blob of random variables, who despite being located on the same row, share no meaning. Similarly, we could write a 16-case program to pick any single location in memory, but this would add several instructions to a single dereference -- an unfortunately unacceptable cost.

Comment: A controller like this makes sense only if its task is extremely limited (you still haven't described what it is used for).  If your goal is to do arbitrarily complicated things on it, one of you (the guy offering oodles of functionality, or the guy offering ultra cheap) is screwed up.

Comment: I don't get the "add memory".  Presumably it comes with 256 bytes already :-}

Comment: You figured out that you *can* implement an indirection (done cleverly, you can do it with 4 or 8 branches, depending on whether you have a "short" pointer or a "long" one).  And, you could use the page selector pointer and slot zero (or 1 or ...) in each page for a favored array with unit access times.   If you need it, what alternative do you have?   You can take some succor in knowing that most programs don't indirect-access at every step, so even if you have to do this expensive awful thing, you don't have to do it all the time, and that may make its cost a lot more palatable.

Comment: Frankly, this sounds like the kind of thing where you code for it in it's machine language for a while, and then once you have a sense of what mechanisms work efficiently at the hardware level, possibly consider if there is some higher level language which would be an appropriate shortcut for specifying those - or not, as the case may turn out to be.

Comment: Assembler.  Nothing else makes sense.